# Why won't approx3d interpolate the last elements of a 3d array?

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

I have been using the function approx3d (from package oce) to interpolate values from a 3d array. The inputs to the function include 3 vectors for the x, y and z dimensions of the array, and NA is returned if the position of the value you are trying to interpolate lies outside the bounds of these vectors. The function works fine when the first element of any of the vectors is used, but returns NA for the last element.

For example:

```
vector1 <- c(1:10)
vector2 <- c(1:10)
vector3 <- c(1:10)

array <- array(c(vector1, vector2, vector3)), dim = c(10,10,10))
```

`approx3d(vector1, vector2, vector3, array, 2.3, 4.5, 6.6)` works fine and returns 2.3.
`approx3d(vector1, vector2, vector3, array, 1, 1, 1)` also works fine and returns 1.

BUT
`approx3d(vector1, vector2, vector3, array, 10, 1, 1)` returns NA.
Why does it consider 10 to be out of the bounds of the vectors? How can I get it to interpolate for every value 1:10, inclusive?